# Show Product options in pop up

Tags: magento2

I have got a product that has lots of colour/fabric/style options for each product. If I add them then it pushes "Add to basket" button below the fold.

Is it possible to show product attributes/options in new popup window or in a tab?

As an example, I would like something like this,

https://www.darlingsofchelsea.co.uk/kingly# (click on "Choose a leather" and you will see that options open in new pop)

or

https://www.sofa.com/gb/sofas/breakdownable-sofas-%28for-easy-access%29/descartes-sofa/p/SO-DSC (click on "Pick fabric" then options open in tab on the page)

Any help from you will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use following free version of extension.

It offers functionalities to support a variety of product types.

https://www.tigren.com/magento-2-extensions/magento-2-ajax-add-to-cart/

The customers can either choose product attributes (size, color, other etc.) before or after clicking the Add to cart button on the Category page and Search results page.

Answer (score 1):

Use the magento modal widget for the customizable options that are in the template (if it's a core template, you'll want to extend that). Then add a button to your template with a JS function that opens the modal on click. Without testing this approach, I would think that adding those options would still pass through to the cart/order.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_modal.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below extension:

https://www.itoris.com/magento-2-custom-options.html

Using this extension you can manage product dynamic options very easily and also you can add the condition on whether you want to display certain options or not. you can check demo of this extension in the above-mentioned link.